# Numeration of documents on PHP

Tags: php, laravel, static, httprequest

PHP, Laravel 6.0: I can't write a working static function or a variable for getting numeration of my documents with increment. Every time I create a document it should set its number (Document #1, #2, #3...etc)

I have checked and tried similar questions on StackOverflow but they didn't work.

I've got an Observer Class which should handle the "creating" event and use that function for setting a new number.
Here are my tries:

```
class DocumentObserver
{
    /**
     * Found this one on StackOverflow but it didn't work
     */
    public function currentNum()
    {
        static $num = 6;
        $num++;
        return $num;
    }

    /**
     * Tried to use a property but it didn't work as well
     */
    public static $currentNumber = 0;

    /**
     * Set number to the document
     */
    public function setNumber(Document $document)
    {
        //set format of document number (XX00000001)
        $document->number = "IQR" . sprintf('%06d', self::currentNum());
    }

    /**
     * Handle the rent "creating" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Document $document
     * @return void
     */
    public function creating(Document $document)
    {
        $this->setNumber($document);
    }
  }
```

I'd be happy if you help me to solve this problem. Any additional advice, in this case, would be very appreciated since I'm new in PHP & Laravel.

Comment: So what exactly is happening with the code you posted? Also note that `currentNum` is not a static function and you're calling it as such (should only produce warnings in most cases, but that's still incorrect).

Comment: Tried use all variations but at the end got this: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'IQR000008' for key...

Comment: This will only work if executed multiple times from the same script instance. If you run the code again later it will start back at 6 (well, 7). If you want persistence, you need to store that number somewhere (e.g. in your database). You seem to already store documents in the db, don't documents have a PK that you can use? (In which case, do you need to store that info again in the `number` field?)

Comment: The static variable won't persist across different requests, so you count will always restart. That's why your unique index fail on the table.

Comment: Its a good idea. Actually right now I use calculation of total amount of documents in DB and add + 1 to this number to get current one.

Comment: Elias Soares, thank you. It changes the case.

Comment: Jeto, PK would be great but in my case Observer handle the creating event before saving in DB and document number is required as well. To implement this I need first to save data without number and then update the number. Im not sure its good every time use save and update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Two requests mean two executions of the script, and two distinct memory spaces. At the end of the first request, the first script ends, and all the changes it made in memory are forgotten. The second script starts from scratch, with all the variables having their default value." from StackOverflow.

Thanks, Jeto and Elias Soares for explainings.

Here is my solution so far:

```
public function setNumber(Document $document)
  {
    //Get the highest "id" in the table + 1
    $max_id= Document::max('id') + 1;

    //set format of document number (XX00000001)
    $document->number = 'SQ' . sprintf('%07d', $max_id);
  }
```